# Kaplansky Idempotent conjecture and Extension theory

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, cohomology, geometric-group-theory

We consider the Idempotent Kaplansky  conjecture with $\mathbb{C}$- coefficients, that is the problem of nontrivial  idempotents for  group algebra $\mathbb{C}\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is  a torsion free group.

Assume  that $G_{1}$ and  $G_{2}$ are torsion free groups  which satisfies this  conjecture. Assume  that we  have a  short exact  sequence  of groups  as $0\to G_{1}\to G_{3} \to G_{2} \to 0$.  Does  this implies that  $G_{3}$ satisfies the  Kaplansky conjecture? What  about the  particular case "semidirect  product?(One  can  consider the same  question for  Kadison conjecture)

A possible  negative  answer is  difficult  as the  original  Kaplansky  conjecture.  But this  is  a reasonable problem if it would have  a  possible  affirmative answer.

There  are  some indirectly related obstructions and  question:

1.A  group extension does not  give  a group  algebra  extension. But we have a complex of group algebras:$$0\to\mathbb{C} G_{1}\to \mathbb{C}G_{3} \to \mathbb{C}G_{2} \to 0$$ so the cohomology gives us a new algebra associated to a given group extension.

2.There are some known properties  about torsion free groups which   guarantees the  Kaplansky  conjecture. We  collect  such  properties in a  set $S$.   A group  which satisfies at least one  of these  properties,  is  called an $S$  group. . Is the  collection $S$  closed under group extension?(Or at least closed under semidirect product?) Namely: Is an   extension of  an $S$  group by  an  $S$  group, an  $S$-group?

Comment: Regarding point 2: it's not hard to show that the class of unique product groups is closed under extensions (see Lemma 13.1.8 in Passman's book "The Algebraic Structure of Group Rings").

Answer (score 1):

This paper contains some results on this topic

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.06424.pdf